# Tensorflow. Difference between [batch_size, 1] & [batch_size]

Tags: tensorflow, dimensions

In [tensorflow tutorial for word embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) one finds:

```
# Placeholders for inputs
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
```

What is possibly the difference between these two placeholders. Aren't they both a int32 column vector of size batch_size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer with a little debugging.

```
[batch_size] = [ 0, 2, ...]
[batch_size, 1] = [ [0], [2], ...]
```

Though still don't know why using the second form.

Comment: The second version is the transposed version of the first.

Answer (score 0):

`train_inputs` is a row vector while `train_labels` is a column vector.